# Telegram curl line break in caption

Tags: curl, telegram

I have a Telegram command that is able to display text on multiple lines using `%0A`

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot$API_TOKEN/sendMessage -d chat_id=$CHAT_ID -d text="Line 1%0ALine 2"
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in a caption text...

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -F document=@"./scorelist.txt" -F caption="⚽ Round $i \nNew Line" https://api.telegram.org/bot$API_TOKEN/sendDocument?chat_id=$CHAT_ID
```

I also tried `\n` but it just prints the `\n` and `%0A` without breaking the line.
Any idea on how to get a line break in a caption text when sending an attachment (if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TEXT=$(cat <<-END
   Line1
   Line2
   Line3
   $SOMETEXT
END
)

  curl -s -X POST -F "document=@$file" --max-time $TIME -F "chat_id=$TELEGRAM_USER_ID" -F "caption=$TEXT" $URL > /dev/null
```